# selecting div with multiple non-nested specific children

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<div class="outer">
    <div>
        <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="className">information that I don't know</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div>
        <span>Some different text</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="className">information that I don't know</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I have multiple `div`s with same class and I want to select specific `<span>` inside that `div` I would do it like this:

```
//div[contains(@class,'outer')]/descendant::span[contains(text(),'Some text')]
```

this will select `<span>Some text</span>` from first `div`.

How do I select `span` with text and class `className` with text `information that I don't know` from `first` div? something like:

```
//div[contains(@class,'outer')]/descendant::span[contains(text(),'Some text')] and /descendant::span[contains(@class,'className')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to get the text of the `span` elements with the class of 'className' but you have to search for them using the `span` elements containing the text of 'Some text' or 'Some different text' in your example.

To do this you can build up your xpath using `parent` and `following-sibling`.

This xpath gets the text of the first `span` element with the class of 'className'.

`//div[contains(@class,'outer')]/descendant::span[contains(text(),'Some text')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div/span[contains(@class, 'className')]`

Then just replace the text of the `span` you are using to search from 'Some text' to 'Some different text'

Answer (score 0):

`Following` axis and position index `[1]` could also be used (but could be more ressource consuming) :

```
//div[contains(@class,'outer')]//span[contains(text(),'Some text')]/following::span[1][@class='className']

//div[contains(@class,'outer')]//span[contains(text(),'Some different text')]/following::span[1][@class='className']
```